# Webpack throws 'Illegal import declaration', suspected config error

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babel-loader

I have am attempting to compile my Javascript (es6) for use server side, the environment I'm targeting involves:

```
node    8.9.1  
npm     6.0.0  
webpack 4.8.1
```

The first part of the code I'm attempting to compile using `webpack` is the file `index.js` and it starts like this.

```
import express from 'express';
import https from 'https';

// Import socket.io
let io = require('socket.io').Server;

// Now import some basic middleware for express
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as favicon from 'serve-favicon';

// Import useful file IO
import * as path from 'path';
let fs = require('fs');
...
```

However when I run `webpack` I get the following error:

```
$ webpack

Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 1bd3f903f9c5ccdc3456
Version: webpack 4.8.1
Time: 684ms
Built at: 2018-05-10 14:51:08
                       Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                   server.js  3.97 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
               server.js.map  2.52 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
../dist/keys/it-test-crt.crt  1.16 KiB          [emitted]  
  ../dist/images/favicon.ico  1.19 KiB          [emitted]  
../dist/keys/it-test-csr.pem  1.02 KiB          [emitted]  
../dist/keys/it-test-key.pem  1.64 KiB          [emitted]  
Entrypoint main = server.js server.js.map
[./index.js] 1.2 KiB {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./index.js
    Module build failed: Error: Parse Error: Line 1: Illegal import declaration
...
```

BTW I am using Javascript in it's es6 incarnation so do need Bable and it is in my configs (q.v.).  Even if I was not using es6 the Webpack documentation suggests that `import` should be respected regardless, see [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/), where the Webpack documentations says:

*Version 2 of webpack supports ES6 module syntax natively, meaning you can use import and export without a tool like babel to handle this for you.*

So my question is why do I see the above error?  My current assumption is I have made an error somewhere in my configuration of Webpack, see below:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context:        __dirname,

    mode:           'development',

    entry:          './index.js',

    output:         {
                    filename:   'server.js',
                    path:        __dirname + '/../dist/'
                    },

    devtool:        'source-map',

    resolve:        {
                    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
                    modules: ['./', 'node_modules']
                    },

    module:         {
                    rules:[
                            {
                            test: /\.js?$/,
                            use: {
                                loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=env',
                                }
                            },
                            {
                            test: /\.jsx?$/,
                            use: {
                                loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony'
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            enforce: 'pre',
                            test: /\.js$/,
                            loader: 'source-map-loader'
                            }
                        ]
                    },

    target:         'node',

    node:           {
                    __dirname: false,
                    __filename: false
                    },

    externals:      [nodeExternals()],

    watch:          true,

    watchOptions:   {
                    ignored: /node_modules/
                    },

    plugins:        [
                    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                        {from:  'images',   to: '../dist/images'},
                        {from:  'keys',     to: '../dist/keys'}
                        ])
                    ]
  };
```

I have not set up a `.babelrc` file as I was appending the `presets[]=env` query to the `babel-loader`.  Just in case it's helpful to know any other version numbers my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
"name": "web-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A web application using react, etc. ",
"main": "index.js",
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nigel-daniels/web-app.git"
    },
"keywords": [
    "web",
    "app",
    "react",
    "redux"
    ],
"author": "Nigel Daniels",
"license": "MIT",
"bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nigel-daniels/web-app/issues"
    },
"homepage": "https://github.com/nigel-daniels/web-app#readme",
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.6",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4"
    },
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.6.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "mocha": "^5.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "webpack": "^4.8.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
    },
"engines": {
    "node": "^8.1.0",
    "npm": "6.0.0"
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need `jsx-loader` for a nodejs backend build. You can remove it and if necessary, let `babel-loader` handle `.jsx` extensions for you:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/, // notice the little 'x'
  use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=env',
    }
 },
```

Comment: Thanks @MadeOfAir that's got me on the correct path.  For me the full solution was to add the little x, but I did need a full jsx builder as I have some server-side jsx.  The full solution was to do the following:

Comment: 1) install the bable jsx preset:  `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react`  2) Add a `.babelrc` file containing: `{  "presets": ["env", "react"] }`  3) add the little x and remove the query so the module rule becomes:      `{           test: /\.jsx?$/, // notice the little 'x'.         use: {               loader: 'babel-loader',  // no query        }      },`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it the express module exports with `module.exports`, while you `import` with es2015 import. I don't think webpack supports the conversion natively. I would just use `require` instead when importing npm modules, but otherwise you this babel plugin might solve it for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs.